# vuejs update child component data without updating the parent data

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

in my parent app there is a method that brings data that I want to use in a child component. 
    currently I update the data to the child component like this:

the data of the app:

```
data: function () {
    return {
        message:null
    }
},
```

this is the created function of the app:

```
created: function () {
    socket.on('new timeline message', o => {
            this.message = o;
    });
},
```

this is the template of the app:

```
<gauge :message="message"></gauge>
```

this is the child component

```
export const gauge = Vue.component('gauge', {
    data: function () {
        return {
        }
    },
    props: ['message'],

    template: template,

});
```

everything is good so far,
    but my problem is that I DON'T WANT THE MESSAGE TO BE A PART OF THE PARENT app DATA
    because the message may update 100 times in a second and  this means that whenever the message is updated the parent app will be updated and cause a performance issue.
is there a way to update the child data from parent without causing the parent up to be updated and redraw?

Comment: If parent doesn't need need information from socket event then simply move created() to child component.

Comment: that would solve the issue; only I want to keep socket logic out of the child component.